# 404 for path served by Cherrypy

Tags: python, cherrypy

For three simple apps: let us use a different port than 8080:

```
cherrypy.config.update({'server.socket_host': '127.0.0.1',
                    'server.socket_port': 28130
                   })
```

Let us set up three apps:

fusionConf = { '/fusion':{}}
  mobileConf = { r"/mobile_to_fusion":{}}
  adminConf =  { '/admin':{}}

cherrypy.tree.mount(fusionListener, r"/fusion",fusionConf)
  cherrypy.tree.mount(mobileListener, r"/mobile_to_fusion",mobileConf)
  cherrypy.tree.mount(adminListener, r"/admin",adminConf)  #

cherrypy.engine.start()
  cherrypy.engine.block()

We can see it running on the correct port:

```
$netstat -an | grep 28130
tcp4       0      0  127.0.0.1.28130        *.*                    LISTEN
```

The application logging agrees:

```
CherryPy Checker:
The application mounted at '/fusion' has config entries that start with its script name: '/fusion'

CherryPy Checker:
The application mounted at '/mobile_to_fusion' has config entries that start with its script name: '/mobile_to_fusion'

CherryPy Checker:
The application mounted at '/admin' has config entries that start with its script name: '/admin'
```

But when accessing the url:   http://localhost:28130/admin -   It is not found?

```
404 Not Found
The path '/admin' was not found.

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/cherrypy/_cprequest.py", line 638, in respond
    self._do_respond(path_info)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/cherrypy/_cprequest.py", line 697, in _do_respond
    response.body = self.handler()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/cherrypy/lib/encoding.py", line 219, in __call__
    self.body = self.oldhandler(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/cherrypy/_cperror.py", line 416, in __call__
    raise self
cherrypy._cperror.NotFound: (404, "The path '/admin' was not found.")
Powered by CherryPy 18.5.0
```

[image]

Why is `Cherrypy` not finding the paths?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `AdminListener` class is mounted under `/admin` and `AdminListener` does not have a `default` or `index` method to be able to mount an instance of `AdminListener` under `/admin` and expect it to work. For instance, with your current implementation`/admin/admin` should work.

You can either:

1. Define `def default(self)` or `def index(self)` in `AdminListener` (replace the `admin` method) or
2. Mount an instance of `AdminListener` under `''`. Like `cherrypy.tree.mount(adminListener, "",adminConf)`, this will have the side effect of having the `adminConf` apply to all the sub-application, so I suppose the right approach would be option `1`.

For example, for option 1:

```
  class AdminListener(object):
      @cherrypy.expose
      def index(self, param=None):
          return "Hello from Admin"
```

alternatively

```
  class AdminListener(object):
      @cherrypy.expose
      def default(self, param=None):
          return "Hello from Admin"
```

The main difference is that the `index` method does not consume url fragments like positional parameters, for example `/admin/one` would not work, but `/admin/?param=one` will work with `index` and `default` (notice the second `/`, is important).

The `default` method is like a *catch-all* alternative, it will be called for any undefined path under the mountpoint of the app.

Comment: Thx!  I found no documentation that `index()` were _required_ and what it does. I looked over the entire docs and a bunch of pages of google search results. Any hints how to get a better handle on using this web framework - for someone that needs to go beyond "Hello world?"

Comment: The tutorials in https://github.com/cherrypy/cherrypy/tree/master/cherrypy/tutorial and https://docs.cherrypy.org/en/latest/tutorials.html covers most of the regular stuff.

Comment: Requiring `index()` is not a "regular" stuff:  it's v specific (and to me unexpected) in `cherrypy`.  Is that stated anywhere?  I mean how did you discover it's required?  I did peruse the tutorials: it's not stated there either.

Comment: `def default()` works great.  I just don't know how to read library developers' minds. There is actually a good _amount_ of documentation. But then why would this not be mentioned.

Comment: CherryPy is ~18y.o.; I believe some info got "lost" during the docs refactoring years ago. It's still in the docstrings in Python modules but not all of them are rendered into docs anymore...